# Maybe PHP remember Color?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, canvas

I'm trying to bulid a site that you can draw on `canvas` and its make it to GIF
So far I successed but I have problems with colors
I explain how my site work:

1) User draw on the canvas and its saven in object in array like so:

```
[{x: 1, y:1, radius: 8, color: "blue"}, {x: 2, y:3, radius: 16, color: "red"} ...]
```

Every move of the mouse on the Canvas is a Object in the array

Now I send it to php page as json, Now in the php page I have Array of pre-defined colors like so:

```
$colors = array(
    'brown' => array(
        165,
        42,
        42
    ),
    'cadetblue' => array(
        95,
        158,
        160
    ),
    'chartreuse' => array(
        127,
        255,
        0
    ),
    'chocolate' => array(
        210,
        105,
        30
    ),
    'coral' => array(
        255,
        127,
        80
    ),
    'crimson' => array(
        220,
        20,
        60
    )
);
```

So far so good, Now when I draw on the image I loop every Object in the array that sent to m from the client , I take the color and create one with php function and draw filled ellipse, The Code:

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= $j; $i++) {
    $colorName = $model[$i]->color;
    $color = imagecolorallocate($img, $colors[$colorName][0] ,$colors[$colorName][1] , $colors[$colorName][2]);
    imagefilledellipse($img, $model[$i]->x, $model[$i]->y, $model[$i]->radius * 2, $model[$i]->radius * 2, $color);
    }
```

Now its start ok, but suddenly in the middle of the drawing its back to the first color that I draw with in the website
I don`t know why is that, I look at data I send to the server and this color dosent appeer there in the location where its back to it.

Images to illustration:

What I draw on the web site:

[image: What I draw]

The result that I get:

[image: Result]

The full PHP code of drawing:

http://pastebin.com/0BGUeCF3

The data that send to server:

http://pastebin.com/CPzpJq7f

Put a note:
In the middle of the chocolate color its changes back to chartreuse even that this color dosent exsist in the data that send to server in this location

Answer (score 3):

OK, The problem solved, I explain what cause the problem and what is the solution

The problem was that you cannot create more than 255 colors to single image
I found this note when I read the comments in php.net

> Note that you can only assign 255 colors to any image palette.  If you try assigning more, imagecolorallocate() will fail.

And in my code I created more than 255 colors, because that its return to start
Now I create 6 colors for each frame and draw by them and the problem solved

Comment: Gifs are limited to 256 colors. You might try saving temporary frames in lossless true color format, then convert the result to gif... *if* the library supports it.